# Using jQuery find() then get attributes of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's a simplified XML file:

```
const mpd = `<AdaptationSet id="1" lang="eng" mimeType="audio/mp4">
    <Representation codecs="mp4a.40.2" id="5" mimeType="audio/mp4"></Representation>
    <Representation codecs="mp4a.40.2" id="6" mimeType="audio/mp4"></Representation>
    <Representation codecs="mp4a.40.2" id="7" mimeType="audio/mp4"></Representation>
</AdaptationSet>
<AdaptationSet id="1" lang="eng" mimeType="audio/mp4">
    <Representation codecs="ec-3" id="8" mimeType="audio/mp4"></Representation>
</AdaptationSet>`
```

I want to get the codecs attribute of the `Representation` element of each `AdaptationSet` element.

```
let mpdXML = $.parseXML(mpd);
let audios = $mpdXML.find("AdaptationSet[mimeType|='audio/mp4']");
$.each(audios, (id, audio) => {
    // let codecs = $(audio).find('Representation')[0].attr('codecs');
    let codecs = $(audio).find('Representation').attr('codecs');
})
```

The code is work perfectly. But I think this is not the accurate solution cause `Representation` element may be more than one. So I add a line of code(now been commented) and it's not gonna work. Can somebody tell me why? Cause I have seen similar example from jQuery document doing this way:

```
var item1 = $( "li.item-1" )[ 0 ];
$( "li.item-ii" ).find( item1 ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### But I think this is not the accurate solution cause Representation element may be more than one.

Your code is fine because jQuery's [.attr(attributeName)](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1) specifically says...

> The `.attr()` method gets the attribute value for only the ***first*** element in the matched set.

##### it's not gonna work. Can somebody tell me why?

Referencing a `jQuery` object properties via `[index]` returns the element directly. This is equivalent to [.get(index)](https://api.jquery.com/get/). In this case you would need to use the native DOM method

```js
$(audio).find('Representation')[0].getAttribute('codecs');
```

To keep using a `jQuery` object wrapper, use [.eq(index)](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead

```js
$(audio).find('Representation').eq(0).attr('codecs');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This question has been confusing me for a long time.